# multiple request with retrofit in android

Tags: android, api, retrofit, themoviedb-api

i create application call api the moves DB with retrofit library and recyclerViewe 
when user choose the movie Show  activity  for detail movies 
Now i implement recyclerView with ritrofit to create  fetch the popular movie data,
this MoviesApiService class :

```
public interface MoviesApiService {
    @GET("/movie/popular")
    void getPopularMovies(Callback<Movie.MovieResult> cb); }
```

this model class :

```
package com.walkatheri.popularmovies;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

/**

 */
public class Movie implements Parcelable{
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String poster;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    private String backdrop;

    public Movie() {}

    protected Movie(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
        poster = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
        backdrop = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Movie(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + poster;
    }

    public void setPoster(String poster) {
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getBackdrop() {
        return "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"  + backdrop;
    }

    public void setBackdrop(String backdrop) {
        this.backdrop = backdrop;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(title);
        parcel.writeString(poster);
        parcel.writeString(description);
        parcel.writeString(backdrop);
    }

    public static class MovieResult {
        private List<Movie> results;

        public List<Movie> getResults() {
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

class detail movie :
    public class MovieDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static final String EXTRA = "movie";

```
    private Movie mMovie;
    ImageView backdrop;
    ImageView poster;
    TextView title;
    TextView description;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA)) {
            mMovie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Detail activity must receive a movie parcelable");
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        toolbarLayout.setTitle(mMovie.getTitle());

        backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_description);
        poster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);

        title.setText(mMovie.getTitle());
        description.setText(mMovie.getDescription());
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(mMovie.getPoster())
                .into(poster);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(mMovie.getBackdrop())
                .into(backdrop);
    }
}
```

this mainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        getPopularMovies();
    }

    private void getPopularMovies() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org/3")
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addEncodedQueryParam("api_key", "Key_API");
                    }
                })
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        MoviesApiService service = restAdapter.create(MoviesApiService.class);
        service.getPopularMovies(new Callback<Movie.MovieResult>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Movie.MovieResult movieResult, Response response) {
                mAdapter.setMovieList(movieResult.getResults());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

               if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
    public static class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieViewHolder> {
        private List<Movie> mMovieList;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context mContext;

        public MoviesAdapter(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_movie, parent, false);
            final MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MovieViewHolder(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA, mMovieList.get(position));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Movie movie = mMovieList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(movie.getPoster())
                    .placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (mMovieList == null) ? 0 : mMovieList.size();
        }

        public void setMovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
            this.mMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.mMovieList.addAll(movieList);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

now how can be able to fetch both popular movie data and high-rated movie data from https://developers.themoviedb.org ? can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a method in your `MainActivity` called `getPopularMovies()` where you call `service.getPopularMovies()`, which uses the `MoviesApiService` `@GET("/movie/popular")`. You could create a similar API for high-rated movies, something like:

`@GET("/movie/high_rated")
    void getHighRatedMovies(Callback<Movie.MovieResult> cb);`

Then create a similar `getHighRatedMovies()` method and depending on what the user selects, make a call to that method. The only difference would be you would call `service.getHighRatedMovies` instead of `service.getPopularMovies()`.

To simplify the code to just one method, you could make a method called `getMovies()`, and then at the point when you initialize `service.(something)`, set the correct method call.